# how can I wait for results in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a bit of javascript code that is getting loading in some data from an RSS feed.

I then need to process that data and then get some more data from another RSS feed, but it is dependant on the results of the first feed.

When I run my app, it processes both feeds at the same time, how can I make the second feed wait for the first to finish?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to load the data.

Comment: You'll need a callback to process the results but you need to show some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setTimeout function which postpones a function call for the number of milliseconds specified as explained at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to treat the loading of the rss feeds like what they are: asynchronous events.

Do something like this:

```
var success1=false, success2 = false;

function onRssFeed1Success() { //lets pretend this gets called when rss feed 1 is loaded

  success1 = true;
  doStuffDependentOnBothFeeds()
}


function onRssFeed2Success() { //lets pretend this gets called when rss feed 2 is loaded

  success2 = true;
  doStuffDependentOnBothFeeds()
}


function doStuffDependentOnBothFeeds() {

 if(success1 && success2) {
   //do stuff
 }
}
```

Comment: I do not have a problem knowing when they finish loading, that is what your solution does. My problem is that I don't know the address to goto for the second feed UNTIL I get that information from the 1st feed, so your solution does not answer my original question

Comment: Since my solution only runs `//do stuff` when both your rss feeds are done loading, it is trivial to do what you wish. trust me, this is the way to do it, and has been for many years ;)